# Problems signing in as a devise user in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to sign a user in through devise but I keep getting the following error: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` in `Users::SessionsController#create`. I really can't figure this out, can anyone help please?

Here is the controller:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  include ApplicationHelper

  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end

  def sign_in_form
  end

end
```

Here is the form I am submitting:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <span id="close-button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right"></span>

    <h2>Log in</h2>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email,  { :class => "form-control", autofocus: true } %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, :class => "form-control", autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
      <%= f.label :remember_me %>
    </div>
  <% end -%>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

It is probably something really simple I just dont understand the device well enough to see what it is. Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: if you have a uniqueness error on the session then I would guess you have a validation on the session that shouldn't exist? User data should be unique, not necessarily the session

Comment: where would i have added a validation to the session or could it be something already in devise. sorry im a bit of a noob at rails

Comment: in your models somewhere? session model?

Comment: I dont have a session model so would it be located within devise somewhere then? maybe one of the modules on the user?